# ¿Cómo añadir salto de línea a un texto que recibo de mongodb?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mongodb, split

Estoy trabajando con Angular, tengo un componente que me ayuda a registrar nuevos proyectos estos proyectos tienen una descripción y dicha descripción los captura en un Textarea.

Cuando muestro la descripción del proyecto en otra vista de mi aplicación me muestra el texto pero sin los espacios que sirven para dividir los parrafos.

Supongo que debo aplicar **JS** para que el texto tenga un espacio después de cada punto **"."** Lo intenté con Split pero no doy con la lógica.

Aquí el fragmento de código de lo que estaba intentando:

```js
getProyecto(id){ //METODO PARA SOLICITAR EL PROYECTO A MIRAR

    this._proyectoService.getProyecto(id).subscribe(
      response =>{

        this.proyecto = response.project; //VARIABLE QUE GUARDA LOS DATOS DEL PROYECTO
        
        //AQUÍ ME CREE UNA VARIABLE INDEPENDIENTE PARA TRABAJAR LA DESCRIPCIÓN. USO EL SPLIT PARA SEPARAR EL TEXTO CUANDO EXISTA UN .
        this.ContDescrip = response.project.descripcion.split('[.]');
  
  
        // RECORRO LA VARIABLE ANTERIROR, MI INTENCIÓN ERA AGREGAR UN <BR> O ALGO PARA SEPARAR LOS PARRAFOS PERO ME QUEDÉ BLOQUEADO.
        for (var i=0; i < this.ContDescrip.length; i++) {
          this.descripcion = (this.ContDescrip[i]);
        }
        

      },
      error =>{

        console.log(<any>error);

      }
    );

  }
```

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer reemplazar los saltos de linea por párrafos con la etiqueta `<p>texto</p>`, en caso de que al momento que se haya escrito dicha descripción se haya añadido nuevas lineas o presionado enter para crear párrafos

Comment: Quizás te sirva esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579093/converting-new-lines-to-paragraph-br-html-tags-can-this-be-a-single-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En caso de que no quieras hacerlo de eso tal como te comente, y para hacerlo a tu modo basta con usar la función `replace` de javascript.

Así:

```
// con esto le decimos a javascript que reemplace todos los putos
// por una etiqueta <br />
this.ContDescrip = response.project.descripcion.replace(/\./g, '.<br />');
```

O así:

```
// con esto otro le decimos que igual reemplace todos los puntos
// por \n que representa un salto de linea
this.ContDescrip = response.project.descripcion.replace(/\./g, '.\n');
```

**Editado**

También te puede servir esta otra

```
// si le decimos que reemplace todos los salto de linea
// por una etiqueta <br />
this.ContDescrip = response.project.descripcion.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: Aunque también se puede hacer con CSS con la propiedad [word-break: break-all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) o con [white-space: preline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu información. En mi caso me funcionó lo del CSS, los primeros ejemplos de código por alguna razón mi aplicación no los toma en cuenta y lo que hace es tomar el <br> como texto no como una etiqueta.

Comment: @CarlosEscobar es por debes insertarlo mediante la propiedad `innerHTML` en el elemento donde muestras la descripción. Pero me alegra que te haya funcionado con CSS :)